# Highcharts showing in some pages, not showing in root pages

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, highcharts

I included Highcharts using php.mysql,ajax in my website. it is running fine in pages with url structure "abc.com/xyz/" but not running un "abc.com/qwerty.php". All other jquery calls are done in header file which is constant throughout. What can be the problem? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's very likely the URLs are relative and not resolving correctly. Please provide details, such as the header file which you are including throughout.

Comment: `code`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dxJ_uCBsir4yQMacwqm_6l.js"></script>
<script src="js/ti.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/all.js" id="facebook-jssdk"></script>
<script src="jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/d92376d6fe0e.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/defaulten.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/a.htm" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: These are the scripts called in the header. Pardon my code pasting.I am new to the forum. Still researching.

Comment: Which web hosting you are using?

Comment: webfaction dev-hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your response to my comment, you are definitely having problems with relative URLs. Change your `<script />` URLs to be absolute. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dxJ_uCBsir4yQMacwqm_6l.js"></script>
```

Notice the preceding `/` in the `src` there. If the scripts are not available from `/js/...` on your Web site, then adjust accordingly, e.g.:

```
<script ... src="/some/path/js/dxJ_uCBsir4yQMacwqm_6l.js"></script>
```

If you do this, you will not have problems referencing the scripts from paths of varying `/` depths, which is clearly the problem you're having based on the symptoms you described. :) Hope this helps.

Comment: A bear hug for you. Worked great. Thank you Ezekiel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change permission of that file.

Right Click that file and Change Permission as Read/view/Write.

I had same problem in CPanel. I done this one. Then it's working fine.

Just Try it.

Comment: I am running a poll. If user votes from "abc.com/qwerty.php" page, vote is cast in the database. Form gets hidden, #container is displayed. But in #container div, no charts is displayed.